# Auto rounding up SQL Server issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have what I believe its a very silly problem but that is killing me slowly and painfully, I've made some research as why would this happen and leaves me clueless.

I have a simple table in SQL Server 2008 R2 which consist of:

```
id int; 
name varchar 50; 
price decimal(18,0)
```

The problem is every time I wish to insert or update and the value is a decimal, per say 12.5, after I insert it, the database automatically rounds this up for me to 13. If I enter 12,5 it will turn it into 125. Why is this happening if I'm storing this numbers as decimals? I know its probably a silly answer but between my lack of experience in databases, and the time I've spend locking for the answer I believe i need some help. Thx in advanced

Comment: Just to clarify... Are you asking how to make SQL Server return an error in those cases?

Comment: For the 12,5 scenario, decimal datatype does not respect regional settings.  It will store all numbers with a '.'.  You have to convert to string for SSMS to display decimal numbers with a ','

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **define** your `decimal` to be 18 digits in all, **zero of which** after the decimal point - what do you expect???

You need to give your decimal some digits **after** the decimal point!

Use something like

```
decimal(18,2)
```

or whatever you need

Read more about the `decimal` datatype and how to use it on [MSDN SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: Embarasingly true, thx for the documentation. I'll make sure to read it. :S